# sending sms using socket in php

Tags: php, sms

can i send sms using socket in php?i have mysmsmantra api..

Comment: (-1) this is not a proper question yet. Please provide a link to the API you have. Also, usually, the API documentation will give you an overview over what methods are available.

Comment: http://www.mysmsmantra.com/api.html

Comment: "Above HTTP API Code are fully compatible with PHP", so the answer is yes. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Curl that's enough to send the HTTP request

Example for the curl

```
<?php 
        // create curl resource 
        $ch = curl_init(); 

        // set url 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "example.com"); 

        //return the transfer as a string 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

        // $output contains the output string 
        $output = curl_exec($ch); 

        // close curl resource to free up system resources 
        curl_close($ch);      
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

After had took a look at API documentation link provided by maggie, to send an SMS you must do an HTTP call to a specific URL containing your credentials.

If you try to implement MySMSMantra API using socket you need to recreate (at least partially) the HTTP stack... so yes it's possible - near everything is possible ;-) - but it's a nonsense.

It's way more simpler to use the available HTTP api in PHP:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.httprequest-send.php

By looking at the php documentation sample and the MySMSMantra documentation you must be able to write code that send sms from php without too much pain.

Comment: In this case, `HttpRequest` isn't even necessary. Simply using `file_get_contents()` would be sufficient. cURL is also a popular and suitable solution.

Comment: Long time I didn't used PHP, thanks for pointing easier solution mattbasta !